# No sound when playing video in ionic app on an iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that plays videos hosted on the internet. When testing the app on a web browser and in the iOS emulator the video plays with sound.

If I download the app onto my iPhone using X-Code the video plays but there is no sound!

Does anyone have an idea as to why the sound works on the emulator but not on the actual device? I have checked that youtube videos play ok with sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering why **sound isn't working in the ionic view app** for an **iOS device**, but it works in an iOS emulator like I was:

The ionic view app comes with a fixed set of cordova plugins. If your app needs a plugin which the ionic view app doesn't support thenyour app won't work in the ionic view app. The sound plugin I was using in my emulator wasn't supported in the ionic view app.

Edit: list of supported ionic view apps can be found here: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage

Comment: Nick, can you elaborate on what plugin you needed? I am having this problem again with my app on iPhone and this time my sound was not muted :)

Comment: Hi @Bill, I do not think that there is a sound plugin currently supported by the ionic view app. You can see a list of supported plugins for the ionic view app [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage). Ionic view and even ionic itself is still very new, so it is not altogether surprising it is currently unsupported. 

I think sound will work once put into the app store but am unsure. I would appreciate feedback from someone who has deployed an app with sound below!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I am clearly an idiot! The mute slider on my iPhone was turned on. Not sure though why this didn't mute youtube videos but did mute my app videos.